# How to add data tables to dynamically generated highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to add data tables to Charts.

I tried the implementation shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/

but it didnt work for me.

I suspect its because how I instantiate highcharts.

in the example above the chart is generated by instantiating the `Highcharts` object.

my code:

```
// data from an ajax call
$.each(data, function(indicator, questions) {

            indicator_type = "";

            $.each(questions, function(question, value) {

                dataChartType =  "column";

                series = [];

                categories = [];

                category_totals = {};

                if(value.programs == null) {
                    return true;
                }

                $.each(value.programs, function(program, body) {

                    total = 0;

                    values = [];

                    $.each(body, function(j, k) {

                        if (categories.indexOf(j) == -1) {

                            categories.push(j);

                            category_totals[j] = 0;

                        }

                        if(k != 0) {
                            values.push(k); 
                        } else {
                            values.push(null);
                        }


                        category_totals[j] += parseInt(k, 10);

                        total += k;


                    });

                    series.push({
                        data: values,
                        total: total,
                        name: program //question
                    });

                }); // eo each program

                var chartDiv = document.createElement('div'); 

                chartDiv.className = "chart";

                $('.charts_wrap').append(chartDiv);

                $(chartDiv).highcharts({
                    events: {
                        load: Highcharts.drawTable
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: dataChartType
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: categories
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 60,
                        x: -60
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<strong>' + this.series.name + '</strong><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        line: {
                            connectNulls: true
                        },
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false,
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                                style: {
                                    textShadow: '0 0 3px w'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: series,
                    title:{ text: indicator },
                    subtitle:{ text: question }
                });


            }); // EO each question

        }); // eo each indicator
```

Answer (score 1):

When instantiating highcharts like this:

```
$("#container").highcharts({ ...
```

The events option needs to be included inside the charts option:

```
$("#container").highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
           load: Highcharts.drawTable
        },
    },
    ...
```